# signrawtransactionwithwallet shows error Unable to sign input, invalid stack size (possibly missing key)

Tags: transactions, bitcoin, json-rpc

I'm trying to send trasaction in Bitcoin testnet.
So I'm doing this: create arrays of inputs and outputs, then call createrawtransaction and get transaction hex. Then I call `decoderawtransaction` and see this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [txid] => b7374ebb31a77eb65cc146bfca8d09ac84e7ced068e121fedee90d6205a8481a
    [hash] => b7374ebb31a77eb65cc146bfca8d09ac84e7ced068e121fedee90d6205a8481a
    [version] => 2
    [size] => 158
    [vsize] => 158
    [weight] => 632
    [locktime] => 0
    [vin] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [txid] => 8d3c81d39d9d852b347490934b78f22137454706ea96c5cb61c1d1336d3c0440
                    [vout] => 0
                    [scriptSig] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [asm] =>
                            [hex] =>
                        )

                    [sequence] => 4294967295
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [txid] => abd5a3c9abf946d90730b37f2f0dd2eab48cf1520bdccf2174a57c49991b5f81
                    [vout] => 0
                    [scriptSig] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [asm] =>
                            [hex] =>
                        )

                    [sequence] => 4294967295
                )

        )

    [vout] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [value] => 0.00091799
                    [n] => 0
                    [scriptPubKey] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [asm] => OP_HASH160 626e89f8d256f31e3f18787e50fc2b874251e004 OP_EQUAL
                            [hex] => a914626e89f8d256f31e3f18787e50fc2b874251e00487
                            [reqSigs] => 1
                            [type] => scripthash
                            [addresses] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 2N2DgdTtbrfBg65c1DrnuzJnAvSWWr4gkNS
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [value] => 0.01509785
                    [n] => 1
                    [scriptPubKey] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [asm] => OP_DUP OP_HASH160 6f4d68c699514a84cf4588bca6b8c7314b90b8c0 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG
                            [hex] => 76a9146f4d68c699514a84cf4588bca6b8c7314b90b8c088ac
                            [reqSigs] => 1
                            [type] => pubkeyhash
                            [addresses] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => mqfU2qaG2BtrEqnovAbcRExvzHByvm1rPB
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

But when I call `signrawtransactionwithwallet` on hex of this transaction, I'm getting error:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [result] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hex] => 020000000240043c6d33d1c161cbc596ea0647453721f2784b939074342b859d9dd3813c8d0000000000ffffffff815f1b99497ca57421cfdc0b52f18cb4ead20d2f7fb33007d946f9abc9a3d5ab0000000000ffffffff02976601000000000017a914626e89f8d256f31e3f18787e50fc2b874251e0048799091700000000001976a9146f4d68c699514a84cf4588bca6b8c7314b90b8c088ac00000000
            [complete] =>
            [errors] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [txid] => 8d3c81d39d9d852b347490934b78f22137454706ea96c5cb61c1d1336d3c0440
                            [vout] => 0
                            [witness] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [scriptSig] =>
                            [sequence] => 4294967295
                            [error] => Unable to sign input, invalid stack size (possibly missing key)
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [txid] => abd5a3c9abf946d90730b37f2f0dd2eab48cf1520bdccf2174a57c49991b5f81
                            [vout] => 0
                            [witness] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [scriptSig] =>
                            [sequence] => 4294967295
                            [error] => Unable to sign input, invalid stack size (possibly missing key)
                        )

                )

        )

    [error] =>
    [id] =>
)
```

Where can be an issue? It seems to be like in tutorial https://medium.com/@piyushpruthi/sending-raw-transactions-in-bitcoin-dacef2269d1b , with the exception that bitoin api has slightly changed...

Answer (score 0):

Yep, in the tutorial, signrawtransaction is deprecated.

1. Do you have the private key of sender? `getaddressinfo / dumpprivkey`
2. Have you load wallet? `loadwallet`

Alternatively you can dump your private key and sign the transaction. `signrawtransactionwithkey`

Comment: `getaddressinfo` shows this: for sender address (there is only one sender address):
```
  "address": "2N2DgdTtbrfBg65c1DrnuzJnAvSWWr4gkNS",
  "scriptPubKey": "a914626e89f8d256f31e3f18787e50fc2b874251e00487",
  "ismine": false,
  "solvable": false,
  "iswatchonly": true,
  "isscript": true,
  "iswitness": false,
  "label": "eobmen",
  "ischange": false,
  "timestamp": 1,
  "labels": [
    {
      "name": "eobmen",
      "purpose": "receive"
    }
  ]
```
and `dumpprivkey` show error `Address does not refer to a key`
Maybe problem is that address was created just for receive?

Comment: Yep. Seems like you don't have the private key of the sender address

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Problem was, sender address hadn't corrsponding private key (I don't know how it happened)